# Hiding a table row after filtering in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to hide the row structure in table after filtering is done in xslt,elements are getting hidden but the row  structure is still shown.

A “filter” attribute be added to the applicable elements and a variable be introduced to the stylesheet that would match on the value of this filter attribute.

Example:

```
       <multi.document version="1" filterusing="k">
           <table>
     <tbody>
      <row rowsep="0" filtering="k">
       <entry align="left">
        <para.set legal="no">
         <para>
          ----
           </para> 
            </para.set>
            </entry>
             </row>
              </tbody>
              </table>
```

If variable value “a” is passed to the stylesheet then the elements containing “filter” attributes != ‘a’ get ignored during processing. If the element does not contain a “filter” attribute then it gets processed normally(output).

Ideally this variable would come from an source outside the XML document, but it would also be nice to have a root level optional attribute that can be set designating what value should be used for filtering.

Ex

```
<xsl:variable name="filter" select="multi.document/@filterusing"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="tbody/row/entry/para.set" mode="table">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="child::para/@change.bar='yes' or ancestor::table/@change.bar='yes'">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ancestor::row/@filtering">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$filter=ancestor::row/@filtering">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="parent::entry/@align='left' and string-length(parent::entry/preceding-sibling::entry/child::para.set/child::para)=0 and not(parent::entry/preceding-sibling::entry)">
                                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="table_cell_cb_atts">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="parent::entry/@align='left' and not(parent::entry/preceding-sibling::entry/child::para.set/child::para/child::node())=0">
                                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="table_cell_col2_cb_atts">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="parent::entry/@align='right'">
                                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="table_cell_right_cb_atts">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
                  </fo:block>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="table_cell_center_cb_atts">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ancestor::row/@filtering">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$filter=ancestor::row/@filtering">
                                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="table_cell_atts">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
                                </fo:block>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="table_cell_atts">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
         </fo:block>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XSL-FO contains a section that creates a `<fo:table-row>` based on the XML `row`.

To create the FO row only when the input XML row matches your filter variable:

```
<xsl: if test="@filtering = $filter">
    <fo:table-row>
        etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is the code used to hide the row structure and it is working fine

```
<xsl:variable name="rowsep">
  <xsl:choose>
  <!-- If this is the last row, rowsep never applies. -->
    <xsl:when test="not(ancestor-or-self::row[1]/following-sibling::row or ancestor-or-self::thead/following-sibling::tbody or ancestor-or-self::tbody/preceding-sibling::tfoot) and not (ancestor-or-self::tbody/parent::tgroup/@sort='yes')">
      <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="ancestor::row/@filtering and ancestor::row/@filtering!=$filter">0</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="inherited.table.attribute">
        <xsl:with-param name="entry" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="colnum" select="$entry.colnum"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="'rowsep'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

: 
-->

```
<xsl:variable name="colsep">
  <xsl:choose>
  <!-- If this is the last column, colsep never applies. -->
    <xsl:when test="$following.spans = ''">0</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="ancestor::row/@filtering and ancestor::row/@filtering!=$filter">0</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="inherited.table.attribute">
        <xsl:with-param name="entry" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="colnum" select="$entry.colnum"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="'colsep'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```